# Avoid overlapping data points in d3 v4 scatterplot

Tags: d3.js

I have been working on a d3 visualization in v4, which is a scatter/bubble plot with data points that have been filled with an image (see JS Bin link).

The problem I have is that a lot of the data points overlap, so I would like to have the overlapping points move until they are next to each other (the exact location of the points isn't too important).

I am new to d3 and have been struggling to get my head around simulation (collision detection, forceCollide etc) and would appreciate some help on how I can achieve this.

My attempts so far result in the initial x and y data points being ignored and the result is one big circle of non-overlapping circles. But what I'm after is the initial x and y values to be preserved and ONLY the overlapping circles be moved (so the outliers should still be outliers).

I've created an example on JS Bin (below) to demonstrate what I have. In particular, the force simulation code (when uncommenting simulation.stop(); ) seems to overwrite the initial x and y values.

I feel like I'm almost there but I'm doing something in the wrong order...

```
  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
  .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(3))
  .force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(function(d) { return d.radius + 1 }) )
      .on('tick', function() {
        svg.selectAll('.node')
          .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
          .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
      })
  simulation.stop();
```

[JS Bin Example](http://jsbin.com/hodutub/edit?html,output)

Comment: Would a heatmap be better suited to the data? So anywhere that multiple data points exist, they are collapsed into a higher weighted/colored group?

Comment: For this specific task, no, because it's a visualization showing people's photos.

Comment: I see what you mean... right, so you will need to use a [clustered force layout](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7881887) with negative gravity (so the pics tend to group around their locations, but push away from each other). Although this example uses a circle packing function, so you may have to modify the logic to avoid your rectangular photos from overlapping at the corners...

Comment: This [force layout](http://d3indepth.com/force-layout/) example also shows how to have different groups of nodes attracted to different center points (similar to your geolocation information maybe?). And Jim does a great job walking through the thinking behind multi-focus bubble charts in [this blog entry](http://vallandingham.me/bubble_charts_with_d3v4.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I'm still struggling and cannot figure out where I'm going wrong. I've updated my question with a JS Bin example. By the way, the X and Y values aren't geo coordinates but are actually the first 2 dimensions from some PCA analysis, so it's a visualization of people with similar characteristics.

Comment: @Matt, did you a solution to this please? I have the exact same problem. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, no I didn't

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar chart issue and was able to get the desired behavior by applying 3 forces: [d3.forceX](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#forceX), [d3.forceY](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#forceY) to maintain the plotted points and then [d3.forceCollide](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#forceCollide) which treats each circle not as a point but a circle with a radius so they don't overlap.

You had a couple issues. First, utilizing simulation.stop() will stop the simulation from running and applying your force calculations. I believe simulation.stop() is used if you want to manually control the simulation using `simulation.tick()` see [d3 docs for .stop()](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#simulation_stop). Also, I don't think using d3.forceManyBody is needed, but if there are other posters with more experience on that I'd love see a discussion. Lastly, I positioned the simulation to run after your chart was initialized. The graph needed to be initialized, so you could then reference your circle nodes and apply the force layout(or so I believe, like I said, I'm still new to d3).

You can check out an altered [JSbin here](https://jsbin.com/taqewaw/edit?html,output)

This is an older questions with no answers, but I thought I'd chime in if it helps someone else, and maybe stir up discussion on some of the parts I'm not as clear on either. Hopefully that is what you were looking for.